# How to retrieve the position each view within a Gridlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-gridlayout

Im new to android and Im wondering if there is a standard method which is used to accomplish the retrieval of all the views' positions with in a GridLayout.

I'm dynamically adding and removing views from a GridLayout like this

```
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            addButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Button newButton = new Button(LayoutAnimationsByDefault.this);
            gridContainer.getColumnCount();
            newButton.setText(String.valueOf("position#"+"huh"));
            newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    gridContainer.removeView(v);
                    addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }
            });
            gridContainer.addView(newButton, Math.min(-1, gridContainer.getChildCount()));
        }

    });
```

I've also tried this..

```
     addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            addButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Button newButton = new Button(LayoutAnimationsByDefault.this);
            Object tag =v.getTag();
            if(tag!=null)
            {      
                int position = (Integer)tag;
                Log.v("onClick", "Position: " + position);
                newButton.setTag(position);
                newButton.setText(String.valueOf("position#"+position));
                TextView text1 = (TextView) newButton;
                String message = "positionis" + position +       text1.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(LayoutAnimationsByDefault.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
            newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                    gridContainer.removeView(v);
                    addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }
            });
            gridContainer.addView(newButton, Math.min(-1, gridContainer.getChildCount()));
            gridContainer.getColumnCount();

        }
```

This creates a new button,but with nothing inside, not text or anything

Im trying to figure out how to update and retrieve the updated position of each view  in the gridlayout,  each time an item is added, removed re-arranged in the GridLayout.

By position I don't mean x,y coordinates, but the 0,1,2,3,4 position as seen with in listviews.

I've tried getColumnCount(); getChildAt(); ActionListener() ActionPerformed() etc. 
Any help, pointers, hints?Thanks!!

Comment: you want to have to position of a clicked view? - attach a click listener on the gridView and it will give you the position of the clciked view

Comment: thnx for the response..Im sorry I didn't explain it too well.Im trying to get all the positions of all the views, anytime any view is added/removed or re-arranged within the gridview. I've tried using 'getView' but Im not sure how to implement that to retrieve the views.

Comment: Sorry I didnt post my getView sooner. I was so lost trying to figure it out, that I rather just try to figure it out on my own before confusing anyone trying to help. In any case I figured out how to accomplish what I was trying to do, but it didnt involve using getView. I figured out how to use getChildCount/at, not sure if I should answer my own question, cause the wayt I solved it wasn't following the same method posted above..In any case, thanks a ton for taking the time!